# How to check that Z80 is dead

Tags: z80

I've bought three Z80 processors (SGS-Z8400B1-Z80CPU [datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet_pdf/sgs-thomson-microelectronics/Z8400AB1_to_Z8400K6.pdf))

In order to check them I use a setup like the one in the following picure ([ref](http://www.z80.info/z80test0.htm)). The only difference is that I use a manual clock and reset (debounced) 
[image]

However there are some strange behaviours:

- The Z80 uses about from 0.1 to 0.2 Amps!
- Output pins assume no logic values (1 volt, 2 volt, etc..)
- Using an oscilloscope I saw that on A1 I have a rectified sinusoide between 0V and 1.3V with a frequency of 50Hz (That is equal to the main power supply)

I double checked the supply voltage and everything is ok: 5 volt with very low ripple.
I had also resetted the processor by connecting the reset pin to GND and then give some clock cycles.

Is this processor broken? Is there any method to be sure?
Because I had tried with 2 processors and I obtained the same results. Before try with the third one I want to be sure to not damage it.
Is it possible that an ESD damage happens?

Thanks :)

Comment: The datasheet lists a minimum clock cycle time so manually generating the clock with a mechanical switch is unlikely to work. As to if that can generate the symptoms mentioned or damage the device, I'm not sure. Many processors use dynamic logic (similar to dynamic memory) and if the clock is too slow, the internal state of the processor is lost.

Comment: Current consumption is about right : read that linked datasheet, it says "200mA" for the Z80B. It isn't CMOS so (a) takes that much power and (b) is fairly immune to ESD damage compared with newer CMOS parts. Datasheet also confirms there is no maximum clock period but the clock LOW pulse width has a specified maximum (so keep clk HIGH the rest of the time).

Comment: Are you sure you have the scope probe grounded, and the tester breadboard has common ground with scope ground?

Comment: All you confident of the boot process for a Z80?  Can it really run NOP, NOP, NOP without setting up any stuff like NMI vectors first?

Comment: @PaulUszak Yes it can. Another guy on youtube did this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZb4NLXx1aM

Comment: Are you using a Zilog Z80ACPU or, as you posted, really a SGS-Z8400B1-Z80CPU ? Maybe the problem is indeed that, while the Zilog parts (despite they put the same maximum limit on low-level time on the clock) still work with TLow > 2ms, SGS parts do not. My suggestion is to change the 1uF cap to 10nF (2800Hz, 0.35ms), and use address 8-9-10 to see if anything happens.

Comment: Make sure all the other control input signals are high (BUSREQ etc). It says so on the schematic but double-check if you have connected it correctly.

Comment: As per the first comment, the Z80 is unlikely to work well with a static switched clock. The Z80 does not run particularily well at low frequencies and becomes very suceptible to electrical noise. In fact, the slower the processor runs the more important decoupling capacitors are!.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to test the processor is to run tests utilizing most of its instruction set and I/O capabilities. Obtain old good console based on Z80 with socketed CPU, and put new CPU in. Cartridge game will be the best test for it. The bonus will be that you will have a console to play with in spare time.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

Output pins assume no logic values (1 volt, 2 volt, etc..)
how you have measured these voltages? With a DMM or an Oscilloscope?
What pins are you speaking about? Maybe the pins left unconnected?

- Yes I'm sure: Z80 can execute continuously NOOP, from the begin to the end, without need other than Power supply, CLOCK running, RESET High, WAIT High, HALT High, BUSREQ High, better if not directly applied to the Vcc, but  with a resistor (i.e. 1K Ohm).
- Z80 don't has dynamic parts inside. This is can proved freezing it with a LOW on the signal /HALT and then let it run free, disconnecting /Hold from GND.